# The best way to construct the image path in jquery for inline css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
$('<div style="background-image:url(\'/images/a.gif\')"></div>').appendTo('body')
```

depending on where I am on a page the path comes out to be like:

http://www.mysite.com/this/is/where/i/am/_images/spinner.gif

I need it to be "http://www.mysite.com/images/a.gif".

I do not wish to hard code it.
I also do not wish to give it a class name and define it with css.
I have tried this as well:

myVar = window.location.hostname + "/images/a.gif"
and use 'myVar' in the jQuery code above for the path. That doesn't seem to work either. I get something similar to this http://www.mysite.com/this/is/where/i/am/mysite.com/images/a.gif"

So I guess my question is what is the best way to construct a path from jQuery to that image. This information that might be relevant as well:

that jquery code is in main.js which is in the "javascript" folder which has the same parent directory as the "images" folder, so "images" and "javascript" folders are siblings.

Comment: Why can't you use that relative path `/images/a.gif`? It should work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

`$("<div>").css('background-image', 'url(/images/a.gif)').appendTo('body')`

Comment: Is there any sufficient difference with the author's code?

Comment: @VisioN I may have misunderstood the question. Not really sure to be honest.

I figured that jQuery may be adding the absolute path because it's parsing the whole string.